# Get `cellTemplate` element on cell navigate event in UI-Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datagrid, angular-ui-grid

How can I get `cellTemplate` element using `GridRowColumn` object of the grid in UI-Grid?

Basically I'm trying to get the elements inside the currently navigated-to cell.

I want to get the current cellTemplate element (which is a custom directive) when I navigate to that particular cell. So, I'm using the following event.

`$scope.$on(uiGridCellNavConstants.CELL_NAV_EVENT, function (evt, rowCol, modifierDown, originEvt) {`

Although the script runs into this event, I'm not able to get the element here.

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE:**
I'm able to get the current focused cell using `$(".ui-grid-cell-focus")`. However, I'm not confident if this is the right way to achieve this.

Can someone confirm?